# Tensorflow no_grad concept

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I know with pytorch you can turn off training by calling `eval()` on your model. 
Also you can set `requires_grad=False`.

How can you ensure that a TensorFlow element is not modified during training?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to train certain Variables in TensorFlow you can achieve this behaviour by adding `trainable=False` to Variables.